# Visual Studio Community ¿Los programas creados con este, deben ser Open source?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

*Anteriormente hice esta pregunta pero no especifiqué bien a lo que me refería ya que jamás había preguntado aquí, ademas de ya no poder responder con esa "cuenta". (Lo menciono para que no me marquen esta como "posible duplicada").*

**Uso: Visual Studio Community, manejo visual basic.net y soy la única desarrolladora.**

Mi duda es esta: Hice un programa, pero **me gustaría que su licencia fuera de Software propietario o Freeware** (tengo entendido, es básicamente lo mismo). Los términos que quiero agregar son: Se puede distribuir, usar comercialmente, extraer el material utilizado que no sea de mi propiedad (bajo otras licencias) PERO no se permiten modificaciones. **¿ES POSIBLE?**

//Sé que pueden aplicar ingeniería inversa para ver el código, ya me lo han mencionado, pero por lo menos me gustaría que no modificaran directamente mi programa//

Espero sus respuestas, gracias.

Comment: y como se supone que lo van a modificar.. si le aplican ingenieria reversa, y despues lo vuelven a compilar con cambios, no es exactamente tu programa...

Comment: Bueno, a lo que me refería es que pueden aplicar ingeniería inversa para extraer lo que deseen pero no publicarlo como suyo, es por eso que necesito respuestas que me permitan saber cómo puedo agregar una licencia similar y si es valido o no hacerlo propietario. Tu respuesta me ha ayudado a saber que esa parte está mal o confusa, pero aún no sé si lo puedo publicar como propietario o freeware.

Comment: me parece que es mas una consulta para un abogado que para un grupo de programadores. Copiar un programa es facil, hacerle ingenieria reversa no tanto (aunque .net compila a IL y lo puedes ver facilmente) y para publicarlo despues deberias demostrar que realmente copiaron tu codigo.

Comment: Lo único que deseo saber es si puedo ponerlo como código cerrado (en el caso de que sí, que esta mal o bien agregarle) o es necesario que sea open source. Lo publico aquí porque sé que hay muchas personas que han elegido una buena licencia para sus softwares. (Vaya que tendré que editar o eliminar la pregunta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debes de tener ningún problema con usar VSC para el fin que le quieres dar a tu software, el eula de licencia lo especifica al ser un unico desarrollador:

> 1. DERECHOS DE INSTALACIÓN Y DE USO.
>
> a.    Licencia individual. Si usted es una persona que trabaja en sus propias aplicaciones para fines de
>   venta o con cualquier otro fin, puede utilizar el software para
>   desarrollar y probar tales aplicaciones.

Las restricciones de distibucion vienen en el punto 3 sección C y estas estan mas enfocadas al uso de logos de Mircrosoft y componentes internos de Visual Studio o licencia de componentes de terceros que uses en tu programa:

> c.    Restricciones de distribución. No podrá:
>
> •  utilizar las marcas de
>   Microsoft en los nombres de sus aplicaciones de ninguna manera que
>   surgiera que sus aplicaciones provienen de Microsoft o que esta las
>   aprueba; o
>
> •  modificar o distribuir el código fuente del código
>   distribuible para que cualquier parte del mismo esté sujeta a una
>   licencia excluida. Una “Licencia Excluida” es una licencia que
>   requiere, como condición de uso, modificación o distribución de
>   código, que (i) se divulgue o se distribuya en forma de código fuente,
>   o que (ii) los otros tengan derecho a modificarlo.

Puedes verlo completo aquí: [Eula Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/es/license-terms/mlt553321/)

Lo cual puedes distribuir tu software sin necesidad de incluir el código fuente.

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que necesitaba.